Calculation question about max(x,min(y,z)) = min(max(x,y),max(x,z))
I am trying to do this calculation $$\max(x,\min(y,z)) = \min(\max(x,y),\max(x,z))$$
I worked it out with the max and min definition I got on a paper and now I need to work out the absolute value. The definition is not the square root definition but this one:
$$|x| :=
\begin{cases} 
    x & \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
    -x & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}$$
Could I use the square root notation if I establish it? Also I don't want to try solving it by cases because I find this way more interesting and I feel it will give me better practice. And yes even if I can use the square root notation I am not sure how to completely solve it yet but knowing I am allowed to do these things will help me in the feature at least I think it will.
Thank you for your help!
Edit:
This is what I worked it out to look like:$$\max(x,\min(y,z))=2^{-1}(x+(2^{-1}(y+z-|y-z|))+|x-(2^{-1}(y+z-|y-z|))|$$
$$\min(\max(x,y),\max(x,z))=2^{-1}((2^{-1}(x+y+|x-y|))+(2^{-1}(x+z+|x-z|)-(2^{-1}(x+y+|x-y|))-(2^{-1}(x+z+|x-z|)$$
I know it is probably not an efficient way but it brings me joy :D

Define
$$x^+ :=
\begin{cases} 
    x & \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
    0 & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases} = \max(0, x)$$
Let $y = x + u$ and $z = x + v$, then
\begin{aligned}
\max(x, \min(y, z)) &=& \max(x, \min(x+u,x+v))\cr
 &=& \max(x, x+ \min(u, v))\cr
&=& x + (\min(u, v))^+
\end{aligned}
similarly
\begin{aligned}
\min(\max(x, y), \max(x, z)) &=&\min(\max(x, x+u), \max(x, x+v))\cr &=& \min(x+u^+, x+ v^+)\cr &=& x + \min(u^+, v^+)
\end{aligned}
So it only remains to prove that
\begin{equation}
\min(u, v)^+ = \min(u^+, v^+)
\end{equation}
but this is obvious because both sides are zero iff one of $u$ or $v$ is $\le 0$. Otherwise, both sides equal $\min(u, v)$.
